# Is it possible to detect that property value has been overridden in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

Could not find an answer for this question.
At this moment using a few mechanisms to inject values and usually another source is just adding a new properties, however had situation when by mistake second file replaced values with incorrect version.

I am able to do static analysis of all properties files before application start, but wonder if it is possible to check it during context initialisation.

One option might be to implement EnvironmentPostProcessor however not sure if all sources will be available there to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use class **ConfigurableEnvironment** which gives the option to get the full name of the configuration sources, then I fetch a map of keys and values for each source.
With that map code can detect keys that have different values.

This is added to existing integration tests with option to ignore specific keys.